# add time from geojson to deck.gl tripslayer

Tags: deck.gl

I am not an experience js programmer, but I was wondering wether there was a simple way of adding the time running as a clock or just a running digit in some corner of the animation.

As a MWE, we can use the tripslayer example from Manhattan.

https://deck.gl/examples/trips-layer/

Thanks